# Java 8 issues printing PS to network printer

Tags: printing, java-8, postscript

Got a weird question for you. Recently upleveled my old project from java 7(jdk1.7.0_10) to java 8(1.8.0.91.x86_64). In java 7 it printed the post script file with no issues and now it is printing the postscript file as plain text instead of converting the file. This is on a redhat linux environment. Simply I am trying to print a string containing a post script file of a file itself.

Here is my original code

```
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT;
    PrintService pService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
// In a field environment, send to the printer
    if (System.getenv("USER_DEFINED_RELTOP") == null || pfr.exists()) {
        if (pService.getName().isEmpty()) {
            LOGGER.error("No printer selected");
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("Printing to " + pService.getName());
            DocPrintJob pj = pService.createPrintJob();
            try {
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
                Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
                PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(pj);
                pj.print(doc, null);
                pjw.waitForDone();
                is.close();

            } catch (PrintException | IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
            } // try block

        } // no printer selected
        // Otherwise, send to a file
    } else {
```

That worked fine in java 7, I updated it to the oracle spec found here for java 8.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/PrintService.html#createPrintJob--

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/printing.fm6.html

```
        DocFlavor psFlavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.POSTSCRIPT;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet attrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        attrs.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);


PrintService[] pservices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psFlavor,
                                                    attrs);
    File pfr = new File(PFR_INDICATOR);

    // In a field environment, send to the printer
    if (System.getenv("USER_DEFINED_RELTOP") == null || pfr.exists()) {
      //Check we have a printer capable of post script
    if (pservices.length > 0) {
            LOGGER.info("Printing to " + pservices[0].getName());
            DocPrintJob pj = pservices[0].createPrintJob();
            try {
                    InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("UTF8"));

//byte[] ba =data.getBytes("UTF8");
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, psFlavor, null);
            LOGGER.info("Doc Flavor " + doc.getDocFlavor());
                    PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(pj);
            LOGGER.info("PrintJob Attributes : " + pj.getAttributes());
        pj.print(doc, attrs);
        pjw.waitForDone();
        fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
                NotificationDialog.show(NotificationDialog.NOTICE_TYPE.ERROR, PRINT_ERROR);
    } catch (PrintException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e);
            }

        } else { // no printer selected
```

This gives me an error java.awt.print.PrinterIOException: java.io.IOException: /usr/bin/lpr: where it looks to not find lpr.

If I keep it the way it was originally (not write to file) it prints the postscript as plain text even if adding the check to check if the printer is post script capable. If I use the new way of printing file I get a lpr not found error. If I print the PS document using the command lpr it converts it as expected and prints fine. If I use lpr -l that doesn't format it prints it document as plain text as well.

Any suggestion/help would be great. I am lost on what to do. I really don't want to convert it to an image and print that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess I'd say that your printer is an HP or at least PCL + PS printer, not a pure PostScript-only printer.

In that case you generally need to prepend the PostScript with a language selection PJL string. If you don't do this then it usually defaults to PCL and if you don't send any PCL commands (which all begin with 0x1B) then everything is treated as plain ASCII text. That would explain why both your application and lpr -l end up writing text, but lpr itself doesn't (presumably it adds the PJL).

You could try prepending the PostScript file with something like:

```
%-12345X@PJL JOB
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=POSTSCRIPT
```

NB the first byte there, before the % should be a 0x1b ESC character, but I can't readily paste binary....

Try sending the file with `lpr -l` if that works then you could try your old printing method.

Comment: so your suggestion worked. I can print using lpr -l a nicely formatted paper. However when printing from java it still prints the text representation. I even tried converting the FileInputStream to the ByteArrayInputStream but got same text representation. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, Java isn't my field. I can only assume that its discarding the additional PJL at the start, and not putting its own version in, but I can't give you any clues why. I guess this is really going to have to be a Java only question.

Comment: Sorry Ken, the team incorrectly patched my code last night. I patched it correctly and its printing correctly. Thank you for all the help.